# Admin API to patch minimum instances for Flex environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to use the Admin API to update the minimum number of total instances for a GAE Flex environment?

I've tried both using the client library as well as the web API explorer and I keep getting the 400 response `"Frontend automatic scaling should NOT have the following parameter(s): [min_total_instances]"`

My update mask is: `automaticScaling.min_total_instances`

My request body is:

```
{
    "automaticScaling": {
        "minTotalInstances": 4
}
```

I've tried different variants of the update mask and I still get the same error. According to the documentation, this operation should be possible.

Comment: Perhaps it's supposed to be `minNumInstances`? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling

Comment: @Alex I've tried that in both the update mask and the request body and it says that it's an invalid field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually not correctly documented but you need to add the `"env": "flex"` parameter, since it defaults to standard in the [Version](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions#Version)'s instance in the request body:

```
{
    "automaticScaling": {
        "minTotalInstances":
    }
    "env":"flex"
}
```

I've raised a documentation update request to make it clearer.